# For loop, list append

Tags: list, python-2.7, append

I have a simple code

```
a_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2_list=[]
for x in a_list:
    a2_list.append(x*2)
```

and I get `a2_list=[2,4,6,8,10]`

If I write code like

```
a_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2_list=[]
for x in a_list:
    a2_list.append(x*2)
    print a2_list
```

I get

```
[2]
[2,4]
[2,4,6]
[2,4,6,8]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

I want to make a list of lists to record each step

```
a_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2_list=[]
b_list=[]
for x in a_list:
    a2_list.append(x*2)
    b_list.append(a2_list)
```

I would like to get `b_list = [[2],[2,4],[2,4,6],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,6,8,10]]`

but I get `b_list=[[2,4,6,8,10],[2,4,6,8,10],[2,4,6,8,10],[2,4,6,8,10],[2,4,6,8,10]]`

It seems like a very easy problem, but I can't figure what I am doing wrong

Comment: first thing (could be just a copy-paste problem) you are missing a 'd' in append for b_list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Fixed the missing character, my bad

Answer (score 2):

That works

```
a_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2_list=[]
b_list=[]
for x in a_list:
    a2_list.append(x*2)
    b = a2_list[:]
    b_list.append(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `list` is `mutable` object. You should learn about [it](http://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/). The possible solution is to copy the list as others suggested.
e.g.

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
a_list = list(a_list)
or
a_list = a_list[:]
```

There are other methods [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).